# Silverlight - Creating a canvas with auto-alignment and scale

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas

How can i create a canvas of this kind - http://www.silverdiagram.net/Projects/SilverDiagram/SilverDiagram_Demo.aspx? I want to position the controls exactly aligned to each other. I want to help users to align it properly using auto-alignment (like visual studio) and by providing user the scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Canvas` is the right container to use as you can position its child control by coordinates. Your problem is more about moving elements around, which is in fact drag & drop.

You'll have to handle mouse events: `MouseDown` to select an item, `MouseMove` to detect a drag and `MouseUp` to drop it. During the move or at the drop, you can change the element's coordinates to auto-align it on a grid or compared to surrounding elements.

I successfully made such a project in Silverlight and used `Adorner`s to add resize handlers to the elements.

I solved the panning and zooming question by putting the `Canvas` into a `Viewbox`, which was in a `ScrollViewer`. If you want to let the user control the zoom factor, apply a `LayoutTransform` to the `Canvas` (available in the [Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)).